# how to configure eslint in astro framework

Tags: javascript, eslint, astrojs

I'm trying to configure Eslint in astro but I can't, then I will tell you the steps I followed after starting the project:

```
npm create astro@latest

npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-astro
```

then I created the .eslintrc.js file with the following configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  extends: [
    // ...
    "plugin:astro/recommended",
  ],
  // ...
  overrides: [
    {
      // Define the configuration for `.astro` file.
      files: ["*.astro"],
      // Allows Astro components to be parsed.
      parser: "astro-eslint-parser",
      // Parse the script in `.astro` as TypeScript by adding the following configuration.
      // It's the setting you need when using TypeScript.
      parserOptions: {
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        extraFileExtensions: [".astro"],
      },
      rules: {
        // override/add rules settings here, such as:
        // "astro/no-set-html-directive": "error"
      },
    },
    // ...
  ],
}
```

after that I saved in vscode to see if it made the changes according to the rules but it didn't, can you help me please?

Comment: English only, please.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize it, now it's ok, do you have any idea of ​​the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I was just browsing random questions. I don't know much about astro or eslint.

Comment: Have you tried vs code the official eslint plugin?

Comment: I have it, for the moment using the standard linter in react projects it works fine for me, but in the case of astro I can't find a way, I look in the configuration but I don't know why it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Having the following config seems to work on my end for the following versions:

```
astro >=3.0.0
eslint ^8.50.0
@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin ^6.7.3
@typescript-eslint/parser ^6.7.3
eslint-plugin-astro ^0.29.0
eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y ^9.17.0
```

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:astro/recommended",
    "plugin:astro/jsx-a11y-recommended",
  ],
  overrides: [
    {
      env: {
        node: true,
      },
      files: [".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"],
      parserOptions: {
        sourceType: "script",
      },
    },
    {
      files: ["*.astro"],
      parser: "astro-eslint-parser",
      parserOptions: {
        parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
        extraFileExtensions: [".astro"],
      },
      rules: {},
    },
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeking a solution in 2024 to use Es-lint with Astro

> **Note: if you are using any other package manager rather than npm just
> replace npm word with the keyword for your package manager like (pnpm - yarn) in every step**

1- first, you need to install the Astro plugin:
https://ota-meshi.github.io/eslint-plugin-astro/user-guide/

```
npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-astro
```

2- [Optional] For typescript, you need to add:

```
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser
```

3- After that create a **`.eslintrc.cjs`** file in the root directory

4- Add this configuration to the .eslint.cjs file

```
/** @type {import("eslint").Linter.Config} */
module.exports = {
  extends: ['plugin:astro/recommended'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaVersion: 'latest'
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.astro'],
      parser: 'astro-eslint-parser',
      parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
        extraFileExtensions: ['.astro']
      },
      rules: {
        // override/add rules settings here, such as:
        // "astro/no-set-html-directive": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

5- Add this to Vs-cose settings.json

```
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "javascriptreact",
    "astro",
    "typescript",
    "typescriptreact"
  ],
```

6- Install the official eslint extension from Microsoft if you  don't already
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

7- Add this to the script object in your package.json file

```
  {
      "script": {
        "lint": "prettier --write  \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,md,mdx,astro}\" && eslint --fix \"src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,astro}\""
      }
    }
```

8- If you want the output to be in a table view you will need to install the eslint-formatter-table package as it's now not part of the eslint core

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-formatter-table
```

Update your lint script to use the table format

> "lint": " eslint --format 'table'
> "src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,astro}"",

9- Finally, check from the terminal with the command

```
npm lint
```